# how to modify the text file in python

Tags: python

I have a text file like the example:
small example:

---

```
@M00872:361:000000000-D2GK2:1:1101:16003:1351 1:N:0:1
ATCCGGCTCGGAGGA
+
1AA?ADDDADDAGGG
@M00872:361:000000000-D2GK2:1:1101:15326:1352 1:N:0:1
GCGCAGCGGAAGCGTGCTGGG
+
CCCCBCDCCCCCGGEGGGGGG
@M00872:361:000000000-D2GK2:1:1101:16217:1352 1:N:0:1

+
```

---

as you see the line after `@` is a sequence of characters. also every 4 lines is related to one ID. in some cases the lines after `@` is a empty space. if this is the case, I want to remove all 4
lines under a similar ID. also the line with `@` is the first line of each ID.

results for small example

```
@M00872:361:000000000-D2GK2:1:1101:16003:1351 1:N:0:1
ATCCGGCTCGGAGGA
+
1AA?ADDDADDAGGG
@M00872:361:000000000-D2GK2:1:1101:15326:1352 1:N:0:1
GCGCAGCGGAAGCGTGCTGGG
+
CCCCBCDCCCCCGGEGGGGGG
```

Comment: And what exact problem are you having?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for a solution code rather than a solution to any problem.

Comment: I would appreciate it bro.

Answer (score 0):

The solution using [***fileinput***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) module (to modify the file in place):

```
import fileinput

with fileinput.input(files="file.txt", inplace=True, backup="file.bak") as f:
    for l in f:
        if l.strip().startswith("@"):
            c = 2
            next_line = f.readline().strip()  # reading next line (line afer `@` line)
            if not next_line:   # if next line is empty
                while c:        # skip rest 2 lines
                    c -= 1
                    try:
                        next(f)
                    except StopIteration:
                        break
            else:
                # printing valid 4 lines
                print(l.strip())
                print(next_line.strip())
                while c:
                    c -= 1
                    try:
                        print(next(f).strip())
                    except StopIteration:
                        break
```

The resulting file contents:

```
@M00872:361:000000000-D2GK2:1:1101:16003:1351 1:N:0:1
ATCCGGCTCGGAGGA
+
1AA?ADDDADDAGGG
@M00872:361:000000000-D2GK2:1:1101:15326:1352 1:N:0:1
GCGCAGCGGAAGCGTGCTGGG
+
CCCCBCDCCCCCGGEGGGGGG
```